# Mathematical calculation to regenerate numeric series

Tags: algorithms, data-analysis

I am searching for a mathematical technique by which I can perform the following,
Let me explain first what i want to do.
consider a numeric series:

```
 23, 45, 42, 56, 12, 56 ...
```

Now, I want to perform any calculation so that at final I will get two numbers at the end.
lets say `33,22` .
These two numbers a such, so that I can regenerate the above series again by applying some calculations.

```
23, 45, 42, 56, 12, 56 ...
```

Is it possible in mathematics.

Comment: So you are asking: can I take a series and convert it into two numbers, and then use the numbers to regenerate the original series?

Comment: Is your sequence finite? Are the entries all integers?

Comment: @GeorgeV.Williams You are right. I want the same

Comment: @user7530 , Yes all are integers. and It should be finite

Comment: I've retagged. This is certainly _not_ number theory. It feels like you are looking for a [data compression scheme](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression), in which case StackOverflow would be a much better place to ask than here.

Answer (score 1):

Whether or not this is possible depends entirely on the details of the problem. Here are a few cases.

**The sequence contains finitely many integers, and the two numbers must be 
integers.**

This is possible. Let $M$ be the largest integer in the sequence; $M$ will also be your first number. Then let
$$N = \sum_i a_i M^i$$ 
where the $a_i$ are the entries of your sequence. $N$ is your second number. To decode the sequence, repeatedly take $N$ mod $M$ followed by division by $M$.

**The sequence contains infinitely many integers, and the two numbers must be integers.**

Not possible. The cardinality of the set of pairs of integers is $\aleph_0$, while the cardinality of the set of infinite sequences of integers is at least $2^{\aleph_0} > \aleph_0$.

**The sequence contains infinitely many integers, and the two numbers can be reals.**

This is possible. First, encode the sequence of integers as a sequence of positive integers (using, for instance, the usual map that takes positive integers $n$ to $2n$, and non-positive integers to $-2n+1$) and then encode the sequence of positive integers as the continued fraction

$$N = \alpha_1 + \frac{1}{\alpha_2 + \frac{1}{\alpha_3 + \frac{1}{\ddots}}},$$
which always converges.

(No second real number is needed.)

**The sequence contains infinitely many real numbers, and the two numbers must be reals.**

Again, not possible, for the same reason as the second case above; $2^{2^{\aleph_0}} > 2^{\aleph_0}.$

Comment: Thank Your for your replay, Could you please give an example.